# Azure DevOps YAML Pipeline set deploy environment based on variable

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to write an Azure DevOps YAML pipeline where I set the deployment environment dynamical in a predecessor job. Here is a conceptual example of what I am trying to do:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: SetVariable
  jobs:
  - job: SetVariableJob
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=environmentName;isOutput=true]TestEnvironmentName"
      name: setvarStep

- stage: Deploy
  dependsOn: SetVariable
  variables:
    environmentName: $[ dependencies.SetVariable.outputs['SetVariableJob.setvarStep.environmentName'] ]
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    environment: $(environmentName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo Hello, $(environmentName)!
```

Something is wrong, as the `echo Hello, $(environmentName)!` just outputs: `Hello, !`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`azure-pipelines.yml`

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
- name: envname
  value: test

stages:
- stage: SetVariable
  jobs:
  - job: SetVariableJob
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=environmentName;isOutput=true]TestEnvironmentName"
      name: setvarStep

- stage: Deploy
  dependsOn: SetVariable
  variables:
    environmentName: $[ stageDependencies.SetVariable.SetVariableJob.outputs['setvarStep.environmentName'] ]
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    environment: ${{ variables.envname }}
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo Hello, $(environmentName)!
```

There are three things to pay attention to

> dynamically setting variables using `setvariable` has different format-pattern in different scenarios

1. across stages setvariable, [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-to-job-dependencies-across-stages)
2. deployment job setvariable, [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#deployment-job-output-variables) have sample code
3. deployment job environment name should be fixed during whole-yaml file compilation, so do not provide the value which generated during the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `environment: $(environmentName)`, as Macro syntax variables `$(var)` is runtime variable.
`environment` only accept compile time variable or parameter.

Compile time variable(**template expression variables (${{ variables.var }})** ):

```
variables:
- name: environmentName
  value: devTest 


- stage: Deploy
  dependsOn: SetVariable
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    environment: ${{ variables.environmentName}}
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo Hello
```

Parameter:

```
parameters:
  - name: environmentName
    type: string
    default: dev
    values:
      - dev
      - test


- stage: Deploy
  dependsOn: SetVariable
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    environment: 
      name: ${{ parameters.environmentName }}
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo Hello
```

In addition, if you want to use cross stage variable, you could use

```
 environmentName: $[ stageDependencies.SetVariable.SetVariableJob.outputs['setvarStep.environmentName'] ]
```

The correct format should be

```
stageDependencies.stageName.jobName.outputs['stepName.variableName']
```

Comment: This results in the following error before the pipeline run even kicks off `Job DeployWeb: Environment $(environmentName) could not be found. The environment does not exist or has not been authorized for use.`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops#q-why-am-i-getting-error-job-xxxx-environment-xxxx-could-not-be-found-the-environment-does-not-exist-or-has-not-been-authorized-for-use